# Missing implementation of interface ITestLogger.OnTestingStarts; (XE5)

Tags: delphi-xe5

Just installed TestInsight 1.0 into XE5.  When I try to build my unit test project (built using DUnitX) with the testinsight directive declared I am receiving the following compiler error:

> [dcc32 Error] TestInsight.DUnitX.pas(20): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method ITestLogger.OnTestingStarts

My DPR contains the default content generated by the DUnitX plug in.  I am able to pull up the TestInsight explorer from within XE5 IDE.  Any suggestions or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this as well in Delphi XE8, so I did a bit of hunting: https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/testinsight/issues/81/issue-with-missing-implementation gives the solution:

> getting the latest DUnitX version and setting the library path properly (so it uses that version and not still the one deployed with XE8) works.

So from the DUnitX repository at https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX, you either download https://codeload.github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX/zip/master (or `git clone https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX.git`)

Then you point your search path to the directory where the current DUnitX is stored.

Finally you build your project (make sure you have the `TESTINSIGHT` conditional define set) and in the `View` menu choose `TestInsight`.

Now you should see test results.